# Do Flash Duel character abilities supplant main actions?

Tags: flash-duel

Many of the character cards in Flash Duel contain what might be considered a main action (e.g. Jaina Stormborne's Charged Shot stipulates a **push**).  Does using this character ability prevent me from exercising a main action?  The rules state you can play exactly one "main action" on your turn.

For example, can Jaina use Charged Shot to **push** her opponent, who is 3 spaces away, back 2 and then immediately **attack** with a 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaina's Charged Shot ability is used at the start of a round, and doesn't supplant the normal attack during your turn. The [designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/12842/david-sirlin), David Sirlin, answered this [question here](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8135256#8135256),

> Q: After using DeGrey's ability Spectral Pull or Push or Jaina's charged Shot, do you still take a normal action for this round or is the special ability your action for this round?
>
> A: Those trigger at the start of your turn, so you do them then you do the rest of your turn. Nothing says it replaces or prevents a combat action, so you can still move or dashing strike or whatever. Using Spectral Pull and then attacking during the same turn is legal and a powerful way to use it. It's especially good in the dragon raid mode.
>
> Note that the dragon does have a card that triggers "instead of his main action," so that ability really does prevent him from doing a main action later in the turn.